# How to find duplicate values in Excel cells between multiple sheets programmatically

Tags: c#, arrays, excel, office-interop

For example, I have a sheet called *EmployeeSheet*, which is just a single column of every employee's name first and last in a company. And let's assume this list is perfectly formatted and has no duplicates so every cell is unique in this sheet.

Now I have a sheet for each department in the company, such as *FinanceSheet*, *ITSheet*, and *SalesSheet*. Each sheet has in it somewhere (as in each sheet doesn't have the same layout) a list of employees in each department. However any 1 employee name **should** only appear once between all of the department sheets (this excludes the EmployeeSheet).

Here's the solution I can think of but not figure out how to implement, would be to make a multidimensional array (Learned a small bit about them in school, vaguely remember how to use though).

Pseudocode something like:

```
 arrEmployees = {"Tom Hanks", "Burt Reynolds", "Your Mom"}
 arrFinance = {"Tom Hanks"}
 arrIT = {"Burt Reynolds"}
 arrSales = {"Your Mom"}
 arrSheets = {arrEmployees, arrFinance, arrIT, arrSales}
```

While I've been able to get single cell values and ranges as strings by using

```
Sheets shts = app.Worksheets;
Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)sheets.get_Item("EmployeeSheet");
Excel.Range empRange = (Excel.Range)worksheet.get_range("B2");
string empVal = empRange.Value2.ToString();
```

But with that process to get a single cell value to a string, I don't know how I would put that into an element of my array, let alone a range of values.

I'm sure my method is not the most efficient, and it might not even be possible, but that's why I'm here for help, so any tips are appreciated.

---

EDIT: This is the solution that ended up working for me. Thanks to Ian Edwards solution.

```
Dictionary<string, List<Point>> fields = new Dictionary<string, List<Point>>();
fields["Finance"] = new List<Point>() { new Point(2,20)};
fields["Sales"] = new List<Point>();
for (int row = 5; row <= 185; row += 20) {fields["Sales"].Add(new Point(2,row));}

List<string> names = new List<string>();
List<string> duplicates = new List<string>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<Point>> kp in fields)
{ 
   Excel.Worksheet xlSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[kp.Key];
   foreach (Point p in kp.Value)
   {
     if ((xlSheet.Cells[p.Y, p.X] as Excel.Range.Value != null)
     {
       string cellVal = ((xlSheet.Cells[p.Y,p.X] as Excel.Range).Value).ToString();
       if (!names.Contains(cellVal))
       { names.Add(cellVal)) }
       else { duplicates.Add(cellVal); } } } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little example I knocked together - the comments should explain what's going on line by line.

You can declare the name of the worksheets you want to check for names, as well as where to start looking for names in the 'worksheets' dictionary.

I assume you don't know how many names are in each list - it will keep going down each list until it encounters a blank cell.

```
        // Load the Excel app
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        // Open the workbook
        var xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("XLTEST.xlsx");

        // Delcare the sheets and locations to look for names
        Dictionary<string, Tuple<int, int>> worksheets = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<int, int>>()
        {
            // Declare the name of the sheets to look in and the 1 base X,Y index of where to start looking for names on each sheet (i.e. 1,1, = A1)
            { "Sheet1", new Tuple<int, int>(1, 1) },
            { "Sheet2", new Tuple<int, int>(2, 3) },
            { "Sheet3", new Tuple<int, int>(4, 5) },
            { "Sheet4", new Tuple<int, int>(2, 3) },
        };

        // List to keep track of all names in all sheets
        List<string> names = new List<string>();
        // Iterate over every sheet we need to look at
        foreach(var worksheet in worksheets)
        {
            string workSheetName = worksheet.Key;
            // Get this excel worksheet object
            var xlWorksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Worksheets[workSheetName];
            // Get the 1 based X,Y cell index
            int row = worksheet.Value.Item1;
            int column = worksheet.Value.Item2;
            // Get the string contained in this cell
            string name = (string)(xlWorksheet.Cells[row, column] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value;
            // name is null when the cell is empty - stop looking in this sheet and move on to the next one
            while(name != null)
            {
                // Add the current name to the list
                names.Add(name);
                // Get the next name in the cell below this one
                name = (string)(xlWorksheet.Cells[++row, column] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value;
            }
        }
        // Compare the number of names to the number of unique names
        if (names.Count() != names.Distinct().Count())
        {
            // You have duplicate names!
        }
```

Comment: I have one worksheet and I want to check for a column and high any duplicates that appears in that one column only?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use `.Range` to define multiple cells (ie, `.Range["A1", "F500"]`)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.range.aspx

2. You can then use `.get_Value` to get the contents/values of all cells in that Range. According to dotnetperls.com [get_Value() is much faster than get_Range()](http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel) (see 'Performance' section). Using the combo of multiple ranges + get_value will *definitely* perform better of lots of single range calls using get_range.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.get_value(v=vs.120).aspx

I store them in the an [Object Array](http://www.dotnetperls.com/object-array).

```
(object[,])yourexcelRange.get_Value(Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);
```

From there you can write your own comparison method to compare multiple arrays. One quirk is that doing this returns a 1-indexed array, instead of a standard 0-based index.